Do i need to install a specific version of Chrome to make Puppeteer 20.9.0 work?
I am upgrading Puppeteer 10 to 20 and I don't quite understand how Chromium is being replaced by Chrome for testing, do I have to install a specific version of chromium to go along with puppeteer?
It's working fine with the latest version of chrome that I am downloading in my dockerfile:
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Just need to know if there's anything else I need to do.
